# Gallery and Slide Show or image transition Library

Tags: c#, winforms

i have searched but not found any good library for c# to make slide show with good image transition Effect for playing image and video slides,
if any  library or 3th party application that support api or import xml as input or smth else that able to  making dynamic Gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use Wpf Solution and this excellent library for effecting [WpfFX](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/)